# uniform shading opacity for union of regions in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, opacity

I am plotting many overlapping regions with MatPlotLib, and I would like them to not be opaque. I can reduce the opacity of each region individually by setting alpha=0.2 (or some number <1), but when the regions overlap they become quite dense and almost opaque again. Is there any way to assign the union of these regions one overall opacity? Screen shot attached -- I'd like the whole region to be as transparent as the bottommost shading, and not as dark as it gets at the top.

Thanks!

-Sam[image: overlapping-opacities]

Comment: Can you add the code you used to generate the plot? It will help to know how you are generating the regions.

Comment: I have a large collections of points for the upper and lower boundaries of these regions, which I load in as `pplots` and then do `for k in xrange(len(pplots)):
    plt.fill(pplots[k][0], pplots[k][1], 'k', lw=0, alpha=.2)`

Comment: There is no easy way of doing this. But from the example, it is not clear why you would need the regions to be transparent at all. What about painting them all in the same greyish color, since `color= "#808080"` looks the same as `color="k", alpha=0.5`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution I've come upon, and it works reasonably well. But it seems like "do not add opacities of the same color" could / should be an option :) -- with the solution suggested I must put these plots in the background, but it would be nice to have different options.